# Detecting object reaching an image

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm new in this field, and I have a question -
I have an image, and an object. Let's call the object, **"ball"**.
The ball is moving, and at some point it reaches the image. And here's my problem -
How can I detect that the ball touched the image?
**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You should model your objects in some mathematics way - for example as closed polygons. Then you can search for algorithm of two polygons intersection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with 2D you could just use a simple Rectanlge Collision detection.
Basically to check if a rectangle is in collision with another rectangle you have to check its X and Y position with its Width and Height.

Below I have a jsfiddle example using the html5 tag Canvas

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/e2dmef7q/

The code which checks for the collisions is

```
function Mathematics()
{

}

Mathematics.prototype.PointInRect = function(pnt_x, pnt_y, rect_x, rect_y, rect_w, rect_h)
{
    if ( (pnt_x >= rect_x) && (pnt_x <= rect_x + rect_w - 1) )
    {
        if ( (pnt_y >= rect_y) && (pnt_y <= rect_y + rect_h - 1) )
        {return true;}
    }
    return false;
}

Mathematics.prototype.RectToRectCollision = function(rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h,
                             rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h)
{
    // top-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x, rect1_y, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // top-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x + rect1_w - 1, rect1_y, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x + rect1_w - 1, rect1_y + rect1_h - 1, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x, rect1_y + rect1_h - 1, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // Check to see if rectangle 2 is hit any part of rectanlge 1
    // top-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x, rect2_y, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // top-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x + rect2_w - 1, rect2_y, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x + rect2_w - 1, rect2_y + rect2_h - 1, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x, rect2_y + rect2_h - 1, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // If there is no collision
    return false;
}
```

Just a quick run down RectToRectCollision takes the x, y, width and height of two rectangles. It then uses the PointInRect function to check if a point of the rectangle is inside of the other rectangle.

P.S. my code I have provided is from an old example I have and it can seem a little scary. But Mozilla site has some nice information on 2D collision https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection